# For each positive integer $n \geq 3$, determine the centre of $D_{2n}$ (help for understand)

Tags: group-theory, finite-groups, dihedral-groups

For each positive integer $n \geq 3$, determine the centre of $D_{2n}$.

**Proof.** Let $F$ be any flip and $R$ any rotation. Drawing out the effects of each operation,
we find that $FR = R^{−1}F$. This is $RF$ if and only if $R= R^{−1}$. Letting $R = R_{360/n}$,
we find that $R\neq R^{−1}$. Thus, no flip is central. In fact, $R = R^{−1}$ if and only if $R = R_0$ or $R = R_{180}$. If n is odd, there is no $R_{180}$, so $Z(D_{2n}) = {R_0}$. If $n$ is
even, we see that $R_{180}$ commutes with every flip, and surely with every rotation, so
$Z(D_{2n}) = \{R_{0}, R_{180}\}$.

About this proof I have a couple of doubts.

First:

> Drawing out the effects of each operation,
> we find that $FR = R^{−1}F$. This is $RF$ if and only if $R= R^{−1}$

How can I determine that this is indeed generally true?

Second:

> $R = R^{−1}$ if and only if $R = R_0$ or $R = R_{180}$

This is clear, but how could it be proven?

It must be said that it is not a very advanced material that I am studying. I hardly go by subgroups. Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the first one:
$$
R=R^{-1}\Longrightarrow R\color{blue}F=R^{-1}\color{blue}F=FR
\\
RF=R^{-1}F\Longrightarrow RF\color{blue}{F^{-1}}=R^{-1}F\color{blue}{F^{-1}}=R\left( FF^{-1} \right) =R^{-1}\left( FF^{-1} \right) \Longrightarrow R=R^{-1}
$$
For the second one:
Assume $R_x$ satisfies $R_x=R^{-1}_x$, then $R_x=R_{(360-x)\text{ mod } 360}$, then it is obvious that $x=0$ or $x=180$ (Note $0\leq x<360$).